# save pixel array to jpeg image file c++

Tags: c++

i have a pixel array containing the values from 0 to 255 ...
i have passed it to my c++ function ...
this pixel array i want to save it to jpeg image file...

how to do it with correct encoding ??

i have converted the array to binary string 
 and saved it into the file in the below code but it just saves an empty image of 4 byte size ...

```
    FILE *file = fopen("/media/internal/wallpapers/04.jpeg", "w+");
    fwrite(binaryStr , 1 , sizeof(binaryStr) ,file );    

    fclose(file);
```

thnks

Comment: post the definition of binaryStr.

Comment: That code will NOT write a jpeg for you. It will simply dump that binary data into a file with extension jpeg. No wonder you get an empty image file. Get a jpeg library that would also write headers etc. to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it looks like you have YUV-data that you need to convert to jpeg. Correct? [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a very powerful tool that can handle this.

From wikipedias entry on [YUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV):
Y' values are conventionally shifted and scaled to the range [16, 235] rather than using the full range of [0, 255]. This confusing practice derives from the MPEG standards and explains why 16 is added to Y' and why the Y' coefficients in the basic transform sum to 220 instead of 255. U and V values, which may be positive or negative, are summed with 128 to make them always positive

I.e. 0-255 is not a valid range for YUV-data

Answer (score 7):

Use `libjpeg`. Don't try to reimplement jpeg encoding yourself, there are too many ways it can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a JPEG library, like libjpeg.

- Independent JPEG Group: http://www.ijg.org/
- Info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sizeof(binaryStr) is 4. So, you'll need to get a length of the binaryStr, not the sizeof(pointer). And it's more simply to use something already cooked like libjpeg.