# Loading and saving to file an image from a raw data memory structure in c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, buffer, rawimage

I have a piece of code that retrieves images from a camera and store them in a structure. The structure provides the pointer to the first pixel of the image as well as the image dimension, its width and height.
My question is: how can I save the image stored in the structure in a say .jpg or .png file to be displayed and processed ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I would suggest using OpenCV - http://www.opencv.org/ but there are plenty of libs that does that...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado using an entire image processing framework to just save images to a file sounds pretty overkill to me ;)

Comment: why don't you just google "save jpeg c++"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [save pixel array to jpeg image file c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044543/save-pixel-array-to-jpeg-image-file-c) and multiple other questions

Comment: @Piglet: the JPEG library is as big as the framework itself ;-)

Comment: It may also be that the camera SDK has resources to save files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I solved it using 'ofsstream' and writing the buffer into a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate the libjpeg or libpng freewares, which are the most complete, but be ready for hard work.